# Avoid overlapping labels with ggplot2 and directlabels using ggtern

Tags: r, ggplot2

This one is a bit complicated. I have spent a few hours trying to solve it. I have a triangular plot made with *ggtern* a package that has to be installed manually from the archive since it was removed.

My data is here: https://osf.io/xmagp/

This code should make the plot work for you if you install the ggtern package.

```
library("ggplot2")
library(ggtern)
library("directlabels")

DF = read.csv("AdmixtureInAmericasData_v3.csv", #this loads John's data
                    row.names=1) #first col as rownames

temp = DF[which(DF$US.State==1),] #subset
US.plot = ggtern(data=temp,
       aes(x=Eugenomefilledratio,
           y=Afrgenomefilledratio,
           z=Amergenomefilledratio)) +
  xlab("Euro") +
  ylab("Afri") +
  zlab("Amer") +
  tern_limits(T=.4, L=1, R=.4) +
  ggtitle("Admixture estimates for US states") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face="bold")) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(aes(label=rownames(temp)), size=3, fontface="bold", color="navyblue", alpha=.5,hjust=-0.1, position = "jitter")
US.plot

direct.label(US.plot)
```

Aside from the last line, this should produce (pretty neat I think):

[image]

When I try to use the directlabels command, I get this:

```
Error in direct.label.ggplot(US.plot) : 
  Need colour aesthetic to infer default direct labels.
```

Any ideas? From reading the help, it looks like it is supposed to work when you have grouped datapoints, which i don't have in this case. Is it possible to make it work anyway? Is there some other way? I have looked at the older questions and their answers and did not see anything useful.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, I will need to add the direct label as an approved geometry to the package, in the interim, this is a bit of a hack to access the un-exported hidden object that contains the list of approved geometries:

Note, I couldn't access your data at the above link, so just used the `Feldspar` set with `ggtern`, for the purposes of demonstration.

[image: solution]

```
#Required Libraries
library(directlabels)
library(ggtern)

#Build Sample plot
data(Feldspar)
base <- ggtern(Feldspar,
               aes(Ab,An,Or,group=Feldspar,colour=Feldspar)) + 
        geom_point() +
        geom_mask() #Manual Clipping Mask as Last Layer

#Hack
.approvedgeom = c(ggtern:::.approvedgeom,c('GeomDl'))
assignInNamespace('.approvedgeom',
                   .approvedgeom,
                   envir=as.environment('package:ggtern'))

#Render the directlabels
direct.label(base)
```